# why does printing the text value in here brings up null?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So i'm trying to print out the value that's newTaskTitle when i press the flat button but it always brings up null , although when i print it in the textField it shows correctly , any idea why ?
for example on the onChanged for the text field , i try to print after assigning the newTaskTitle value to the newText , it prints the value
if I then try to print the value on the onPressed in the flat button , it print null .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
    import 'package:todoey/models/task.dart';
    
    class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        String newTaskTitle;
    
        return Container(
          color: Color(0xff757575),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Add Task',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
                TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (newText) {
                    newTaskTitle = newText;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  onPressed: () {
                    //addTaskCallback(newTaskTitle);
                    print(newTaskTitle);
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Add',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the state of the widget.

The widget you are using is stateless, that is, it does not manipulate states, a solution (There are many) is to transform your widget from stateless to stateful.

Then you could use a SetState or ValueNotifier to modify the value.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddTaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  AddTaskScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddTaskScreenState createState() => _AddTaskScreenState();
}

class _AddTaskScreenState extends State<AddTaskScreen> {
  String newTaskTitle = '';



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          color: Color(0xff757575),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Add Task',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
                TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (newText) {
                    newTaskTitle = newText;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Add',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , just since i'm not very clear yet on state , how am i changing the state in here ? i assumed if i'm trying to change an element of the UI that counts as state , does also changing a value of a variable count as changing the state ?

Comment: You are using a "Stateless" Widget, this means that it has no state, it is static, it only shows information, instead you can transform the widget you have to one of type "Stateful" like the example I put, there you could use the function "setState "to update the value of your variable.

Comment: got it so if I'm changing variables it needs to be stateful not stateless

Comment: It is something a bit complicated if you are just starting out, it does not necessarily have to be stateful to modify the state, you could also use "state managers" to manipulate this behavior in stateless type widget, such as: provider, bloc, riverpod, get, etc. .

I hope I've helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the state of stateless widget. Convert your widget to StatefulWidget by  clicking on `Stateless` and then pressing `Ctrl + .`, select convert to Stateful widget and then test app again.

Comment: Thank you , just since i'm not very clear yet on state , how am i changing the state in here ? i assumed if i'm trying to change an element of the UI that counts as state , does also changing a value of a variable count as changing the state ?

Comment: Simply put, state is just a data your widget keeps. Here you define `newTaskTitle` and it is a state of your `AddTaskScreen` widget. If it is stateless it is immutable, and if stateful - mutable.